# AlertDialog.Builder cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog

So I'm trying to build a popup window that displays 3 lines:
-The time
-The incident type
-The location

I then have two buttons, OK (This closes the popup) and Send to Map (This submits an explicit intent to Google Maps and sends the location to it, I have yet to write this code)

For some strange reason, I get an error in Eclipse where it says "AlertDialog.Builder cannot be resolved to a type." I assume I've imported it correctly, as well as cleaned it multiple times. I'm unsure how to proceed. Thank you for your assistance.

```
import android.R;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class AlertDialog 
{
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setMessage("Time: " + SMSReceiver.getTime() + "\nIncident: " + 
    SMSReceiver.getCallType() + "\nLocation: " + SMSReceiver.getAddress())
    .setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {


        }
    })
    .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {


        }
    });

    return builder.create();

    }
}
```

Comment: `AlertDialog` is in-built class of Android Package, you can not use that name, try some another name AlertDialog1 like

Comment: Forgive me for being confused, but you suggest it should be changed to:

AlertDialog1.Builder builder = new AlertDialog1.Builder(this);

is this correct?

Comment: No, your class name should be changed to AlertDialog1 , also your class file name should be changed too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its actually not an error, you have by mistake created a class name with AlertDialog which is actually already resides in the android Package. Now when you have created the class with AlertDialog  and you are trying to access its Builder method it gives you an error, because your custom class doesnt have that method.

Simple solution for your question is just rename your AlertDialog class to some other class name and your problem will get solve.

Note : there is no other error in your code.

I suggest you to change your class name to any other name for example say MyAlertDialog, then your class code will be like below, ( also you need to change your file name according your public class as rule of Java File naming convention,

```
public class MyAlertDialog // See change is here
{
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setMessage("Time: " + SMSReceiver.getTime() + "\nIncident: " + 
                SMSReceiver.getCallType() + "\nLocation: " + SMSReceiver.getAddress())
                .setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {


                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {


                    }
                });

        return builder.create();

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! That fixes everything. I completely forgot my class name shared that. AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Something); <- What should I change 'Something' to? I'm not sure of the structure of this code.

Answer (score 3):

Because your class name is AlertDialog. In your onCreateDialog() function,

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
```

In this line, thie "AlterDialog" is actually reference to your self defined AlterDialog class. If you change to this, it should be work.

```
android.app.AlertDialog.Builder builter = new android.app.AlertDialog.Builder(this);
```